# What (of bad) can happen if I state a constant value using '||='?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, constants, declaration

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.0.9 and *I would like to know what (of bad) can happen if* I state a constant value as this:

```
MAX_LENGTH ||= 30
```

**BTW**: I am developing an "acts_as_something" plugin (in my application more than one class "acts_as_something") and I *must* state constant values like above in order to not show\generate "warning messages" in the `/.../log/apache2/error.log` (production mode) as the following:

```
warning: already initialized constant MAX_LENGTH
```

Comment: @theIV - I corrected the word.

Comment: cool. I didn't want to correct it because then I thought you might never notice/not correct it in your source :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warnings in general are never good. You might want to switch it to this:

```
unless (const_defined?(:MAX_LENGTH))
  MAX_LENGTH = 30
end
```

Comment: Is that the same as stating 'MAX_LENGTH ||= 30'?

Comment: It's better because it doesn't trip a warning by properly checking if the constant is defined first. If you can avoid using a constant you might want to do that. A method that returns a constant value for example: `def max_length; 30; end`

Comment: Sorry for my "insistence", but I would like to better understand the difference between the use of '||=' instead of the 'unless' statement...

Comment: Especially given that the `||=` version does not emit a warning either – and looks considerably more ruby-esque.

Comment: Although `||=` version doesn't generate warnings, it does seem irregular. Constants are generally supposed to bed defined once and once only, hence the term *constant*, but if you want to rip them out and replace them it is possible. The one caveat of the `||=` method is it will stomp deliberately `nil` or `false` values. The `const_defined?` method is more correct in that it checks if the constant is defined, not what it is defined as.